# Inexhaustible generator

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a inexhaustible generator that always returns the number 4 using something from itertools. A sample output is below.

number = number_4()

```
next(number) == 4
    True
next(number) == 4
    True
next(number)
    4
next(number)
    4
next(number)
    4
```

Is there a reason this code wont work?

```
def number_4(): 
    """Return a generator that always returns the number 4"""
    itertools.repeat(4) = infinite
    return infinite

number = number_4()
print(next(number) == 4)
print(next(number))
```

Comment: `itertools.repeat(4)`

Comment: The error in your function is that the assignment is backwards: `itertools.repeat(4) = infinite` should be `infinite = itertools.repeat(4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

```
>>> four = itertools.repeat(4)
>>> next(four)
4
>>> next(four)
4
```